# Loading lat and long from SQL Database into google maps

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, google-maps, informix

I want to modify my asp.net application to open a google maps location from a hyperlink (https://maps.google.com/maps/ms? msid=217765347979644002223.00048600fdc1ccf2d2d55&msa=0). I need to retrieve the lat, and longitude from a db table I already have and dynamically input them into the link above. My goal is basically to have the user click on the link it, it retrieves the lat, long, from the table, and returns or opens the google maps link via web browser.

Comment: I don't believe your question has anything to do with the Google Maps API v3, unless you are going to display your "My Places" content from KML using KmlLayer.  The [URL](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=217765347979644002223.00048600fdc1ccf2d2d55&msa=0) you provided is to Google Maps.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything in regards to the database loading the lat, and long dynamically. What I have done was written some javascript code to open the link, which is saved under my places using KmlLayer.@peterm

Comment: https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=217765347979644002223.00048600fdc1ccf2d2d55&msa=0&ll=29.20651,-81.050177&spn=0.01062,0.021007&iwloc=lyrftr:msid:217765347979644002223.00048600fdc1ccf2d2d55,0004c0a1eef4be99879d5 @geocodezip  sorry this is a better link. I am trying to display content from the custom overlay I created using KML.

Comment: That is still a Google Maps link, [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoA.html?lat=29.202317&lng=-81.049430&zoom=20&type=h&filename=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fie%3DUTF8%26authuser%3D0%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D217765347979644002223.00048600fdc1ccf2d2d55) is an example using KmlLayer.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Informix

Comment: I'm not sure there's much of a dependency on the DBMS in use.  It is not clear from the quoted URL where or how the latitude and longitude are embedded into the query string, but the basic operation is 'SELECT lat, long FROM TheTable WHERE ...', and then create a URL in the JavaScript code that contains those values.  You might be able to do the formatting in pure (Informix) SQL, but probably not; it depends on how the data is stored, etc, and on the formatting requirements.

Comment: @geocodezip , yes I only need to return the link to the google map nothing else. But this link should have the current lat, and long, of that building I chose.

Comment: change tag from Google Maps API v3 to Google Maps, question not about the API

Comment: @geocodezip My apologies. Still thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for but this is a good article on how to create a mvc display template for spatial db type using google maps http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx

Comment: though not exactly what I was looking for it did help thank you.